# uwsim: uwsimbenchmarks/GTpublish.h: No such file or directory

Tags: ros, catkin-make, uwsim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi i am trying to run the demo of pipe following for UWSIM

> http://www.irs.uji.es/uwsim/wiki/index.php?title=Let%27s_do_it:_Pipe_following

I am running the line

```
catkin_make install
```

And i having the error:

```
[ 76%] Built target uwsim_binary
[ 80%] Built target uwsim_plugins_simdev
[ 81%] Building CXX object benchmarks/uwsimbenchmarks/CMakeFiles/uwsimbenchmarks.dir/src/main.cpp.o
In file included from /home/wilmer/uwsim_ws/src/benchmarks/uwsimbenchmarks/src/Benchmark.h:8:0,
                 from /home/wilmer/uwsim_ws/src/benchmarks/uwsimbenchmarks/src/main.cpp:13:
/home/wilmer/uwsim_ws/src/benchmarks/uwsimbenchmarks/src/Measures.h:12:39: fatal error: uwsimbenchmarks/GTpublish.h: No such file or directory
 #include <uwsimbenchmarks/GTpublish.h>
                                       ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [benchmarks/uwsimbenchmarks/CMakeFiles/uwsimbenchmarks.dir/src/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [benchmarks/uwsimbenchmarks/CMakeFiles/uwsimbenchmarks.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make install -j1 -l1" failed
```

How can I solve this?
Indigo/Ububtu 14.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242208/uwsim:-uwsimbenchmarks/gtpublish.h:-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [Wilmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/27812/wilmer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2016-08-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-08-23**:
May I suggest a title change/edit? "error 81%" doesn't really describe your problem. Perhaps something like: "uwsim: uwsimbenchmarks/GTpublish.h: No such file or directory" (without the quotes)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When installing the catkin compiles, and the problem is the compilation, It those not found <uwsimbenchmarks/GTpublish.h>, check you dependencies, CMakefile.txt and the package.xml, the problem is there.

Rodrigo

---

Originally posted by [Rodrigo Lourenço](https://answers.ros.org/users/27752/rodrigo-louren%C3%A7o/) with karma: 61 on 2016-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0